# How to use await in map?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is an array of layes:

```
this.layers = [
      new ThematicLayers(
        this.userRoles,
        this.layersManager,
        this.map
      ),
      new CommonLayers(
        this.userRoles,
        this.layersManager,
        this.map
      ),
    ];
```

And abstraction:

```
export abstract class Layer {
  protected layers: Promise<any> = Promise.resolve(null);

  protected layerGroup: LayerGroup;

  protected grouppedNodes: Map<ITreeNode, ITreeNode[]>;

  abstract load(): Promise<LayerGroup>;

  abstract prepareLayers<T>(layers: T[]): T;

  abstract hasPermission(): boolean;

  abstract createLayersGroup(): void;
 
  get group() {
    return this.layerGroup;
  }

  get stateLayers() {
    return this.reonMap.state;
  }

}
```

I try iterate the `this.layers`:

```
  async getLayersGroups(): Promise<LayerGroup[]> {
    return this.layers.map((layer: Layer) => {
      layer.prepareLayers(await layer.load());
      layer.createLayersGroup();
      return layer.group;
    });
  }
```

Problem is on line:

```
layer.prepareLayers(await layer.load());
```

How to use await in map?

Comment: Would `Promise.all` help here?

Comment: Could you show, how to apply it instead `map()`?

Comment: It wouldn't replace `map`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Nope, I can not use promise.all because I need to get result not from aboth  promises, it can be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way would be to add a async in front of the map callback:

```js
 async getLayersGroups(): Promise<LayerGroup[]> {
    return this.layers.map(async(layer: Layer) => {
      layer.prepareLayers(await layer.load());
      layer.createLayersGroup();
      return layer.group;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why did you copy the code and posted them? What is difference?

Comment: The difference is the async in fornt of layer: this.layers.map(async(layer: Layer)

Comment: Yes, I see sorry, will try

Comment: Doesn't `getLayersGroups` still need to be called with `Promise.all`?

Comment: Yes, still be necessary.